# Centralizer of $A$ is equal to $\langle A \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 1 & b \end{pmatrix}.$$
How to prove or disprove that the centralizer of $A$ is equal to $\langle A \rangle$ (matrices generated by A)?

For a matrix to be in the centralizer I think by its definition it must commute with $A$. I considered the matrix
$$C=\begin{pmatrix} c & d \\ e & f \end{pmatrix},$$so that $$AC=\begin{pmatrix}ae & af\\ c+be & d+bf\end{pmatrix},\qquad CA=\begin{pmatrix}d & ac+bd \\ f & ae+bf\end{pmatrix}.$$ So I must equate their entries and say $$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} ae & = & d\\af & =& ac+bd\\ c+be & = & f \end{array}\right.$$

Where can I go from here?

Comment: I edited to get the math displayed correctly. I also corrected a typo in the equations at the end, you should get $af=ac+bd$ for the last one.

Comment: Also, do you mean "*subspace* generated by $A$" for $\langle A\rangle$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I imagine he means the completion of the span of $\mathbb 1$ and $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that multiplying $f=c+be$ by $a$ yields $$af=ac+abe=ac+bd$$because $ae=d$, so you can drop the second equation. So the only conditions needed are $d=ae$ and $f=c+be$, so any matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}c & ae \\ e & c+be\end{pmatrix}$$is in the centralizer of $A$. In particular, you can take $e=0$, and get (unsurprisingly) that any matrix of the form $cI$ commutes with $A$, even though it is not necessarily a multiple of $A$; thus the centralizer is not generated by $A$ as a vector space. But notice that
$$\begin{pmatrix}c & ae \\ e & c+be\end{pmatrix}=c\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}+e\begin{pmatrix}0 & a \\ 1 & b\end{pmatrix},$$so the centraliser is actually the subspace generated by $I$ and $A$. Note also that
$$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}a & ab \\ b & a+b^2\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0 & a \\ 1 & b\end{pmatrix}=aI+bA,$$thus the *subalgebra* of matrices commuting with $A$ is generated by $A$ *as a subalgebra*.